# how to restrict seeing vendor bill report in accounting invoice in odoo16 ? (move_type)

Tags: github, stack-overflow, odoo-16

@api.model
def _get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form',toolbar=False, submenu=False, **options):

res = super()._get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)

```
    field_info =self.env['account.move'].fields_get(['move_type'])
    move_type_options = field_info['move_type']['selection']
    in_invoice_options = [option for option in move_type_options if option[0] == 'in_invoice']
    if view_type == 'form' and self._name == 'account.move' and in_invoice_options and in_invoice_options[0][0] == 'in_invoice':
        if 'invoice' in res and 'report_customer_invoice' in res['invoice']:
            del res['invoice']['report_customer_invoice']
    return res
```

it is not working .. please help to correct the code . thank you

Answer (score 0):

class AccountMove(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.move"

```
@api.model
def get_views(self, views, options=None):
    res = super().get_views(views, options)
    default_type = self._context.get('default_move_type', False)
    
    if default_type and default_type in ['in_invoice','out_refund','out_receipt','in_receipt']:
        remove_report_id = self.env.ref(
            "zb_account_reports.report_customer_invoice").id
        toolbar = res["views"]["form"]["toolbar"]
        if res["views"].get("form", {}) and remove_report_id and \
                toolbar and toolbar and toolbar.get('print'):
            remove_report_record = [rec for rec in toolbar.get(
                'print') if rec.get("id") == remove_report_id]
            if remove_report_record and remove_report_record[0]:
                toolbar.get('print').remove(remove_report_record[0])
    return res
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).